# Storing GameObjects in arrays in list of custom classes - Unity3D and C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

What I have in mind is to create a list of custom class containing the obstacle prefab, storing around 5 instances of each obstacle type. So the list will look something like this:

```
Obstacle Type [0] ------> [0] Instance 1
                          [1] Instance 2
                          [2] Instance 3...

Obstacle Type [1] ------> [0] Instance 1
                          [1] Instance 2
                          [2] Instance 3...
```

I am currently programming a 3D Runner Game in Unity3D and programming the Obstacle Generator script. I initially started out with List> but found that creating a custom class would be better. So I created the custom class ObstacleSpawned that includes a GameObject[] that should include the instances of that type of obstacle but I am having a null reference exception at

```
obsItem.spawnedObstacles.Add (obstacle);
```

and when I try to figure out what's the problem, it's the spawnedObstacles because it gives null reference exception too at

```
print (obsItem.spawnedObstacles);
```

that I don't know how to resolve. I don't even know that the code will work or not.

```
[Serializable]
public class ObstacleTypes {
    public GameObject prefab;
    public string name;
}

[Serializable]
public class ObstacleSpawned {
    public List<GameObject> spawnedObstacles = new List<GameObject>();
}

public class ObstacleGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    // variables
    public ObstacleTypes[] obstacles;
    public List<ObstacleSpawned> obstaclesSpawned = new List<ObstacleSpawned> ();

    [SerializeField] int numberOfInstances;

    void Awake () {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfInstances; x++) {
            ObstacleSpawned obsItem = null;
            for (int y = 0; y < obstacles.Length; y++) {
                GameObject obstacle = Instantiate (obstacles [y].prefab, transform) as GameObject;
                obstacle.name = obstacles [y].name;
                obstacle.SetActive (false);
                //obsItem.spawnedObstacles.Add (obstacle);
                print (obsItem.spawnedObstacles);
            }
            obstaclesSpawned.Add (obsItem);
        }
    }

}
```

The expected results should be in the form of a list containing ObstacleSpawned classes each containing number of instances. I am trying to do that but it gives me null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `ObstacleSpawned obsItem = null;` then trying to reference a property on obsItem, which gives you NRE. Change it to `ObstacleSpawned obsItem = new ObstacleSpawned();` as such:

```
void Awake () {
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfInstances; x++) {
        ObstacleSpawned obsItem = new ObstacleSpawned();
        for (int y = 0; y < obstacles.Length; y++) {
            GameObject obstacle = Instantiate (obstacles [y].prefab, transform) as GameObject;
            obstacle.name = obstacles [y].name;
            obstacle.SetActive (false);
            //obsItem.spawnedObstacles.Add (obstacle);
            print (obsItem.spawnedObstacles);
        }
        obstaclesSpawned.Add (obsItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not very useful with the `Add()` line commented out.

Comment: Naturally, that's the code OP supplied however. I merely fixed the bug, how OP wish to use it is up to them.